# Loop of all files (recursively) with .txt extension and their path

Tags: php, xml, loops, livesearch

I made a FAQ plugin in which each question and answer are stored as two separate text files (question.txt and answer.txt) in sub-folders depending on their category.

Now I am trying to make a live search for all the questions.txt (their content) and the associated path (link). To do that, I know that I need an XML file (as explained [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp)) listing each item that will appear in the suggestions.

However, as I will add/modify/remove FAQ items regularly, the XML file will have to be updated every time. For this reason, I made a PHP file that creates an XML file and replaces the previous outdated file each time we open it.

**The problem is:** I just don't know how to make a loop for the PHP file to get each question.txt and their path and include them in the XML file.

Here is the PHP file mentioned:

```
 <?php 
  $pages = array(); 
  $pages [] = array( 
  'title' => 'exemple', 
  'url' => '#',
  ); 
  $pages [] = array( 
  'title' => 'exemple', 
  'url' => '#',
  );


  $doc = new DOMDocument(); 
  $doc->formatOutput = true; 

  $r = $doc->createElement( "pages" ); 
  $doc->appendChild( $r ); 

  foreach( $pages as $link ) 
  { 
  $b = $doc->createElement( "link" ); 

  $title = $doc->createElement( "title" ); 
  $title->appendChild( 
  $doc->createTextNode( $link['title'] ) 
  ); 
  $b->appendChild( $title ); 

  $url = $doc->createElement( "url" ); 
  $url->appendChild( 
  $doc->createTextNode( $link['url'] ) 
  ); 
  $b->appendChild( $url ); 

  $r->appendChild( $b ); 
  } 

  echo $doc->saveXML(); 
  $doc->save("links.xml") 
  ?>
```

Comment: why can't you use a normal database?

Comment: This is what you need: [RecoursiveDirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/de/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php)

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your prompt reply. I am trying to do it without database so it can be integrated as easily as possible. I'll check the link you provided, however, I'm not sure if I'll be able to implement that on my own... my knowledge in PHP is still very basic, unfortunately. :(

Comment: Give it a try with the examples provided in the manual. If you get stuck or have a specific problem we're happy to help.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried many things for a very long time but I wan't able to find the solution. However, I did find how to list all files ending with .txt recursively. Although, I would need to "only" find all files named question.txt. Then, I still don't know how to "store" the path and the content of the file in order to make a loop out of it. If you have any other link, I would be very thankful.

Comment: Any suggestion? :)

Comment: please issue a new question with the new code.

Comment: Done. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48669292/generate-an-xml-file-out-of-a-php-loop :)